# "PassthroughSubject" seems to be thread-unsafe, is this a bug or limitation?

Tags: swift, combine

"PassthroughSubject" seems to be thread-unsafe. Please see the code below, I'm sending 100 values concurrently to a subscriber which only request `.max(5)`. Subscriber should only get 5 values I think, but it actually got more. Is this a bug or limitation?

```swift
// Xcode11 beta2

var count = 0
let q = DispatchQueue(label: UUID().uuidString)
let g = DispatchGroup()

let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
let subscriber = AnySubscriber<Int, Never>(receiveSubscription: { (s) in
    s.request(.max(5))
}, receiveValue: { v in
    q.sync {
        count += 1
    }
    return .none
}, receiveCompletion: { c in
})
subject.subscribe(subscriber)

for i in 0..<100 {
    DispatchQueue.global().async(group: g) {
        subject.send(i)
    }
}

g.wait()
print("receive", count)  // expected 5, but got more(7, 9...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `prefix` [operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/passthroughsubject) can help:

```
/// Republishes elements up to the specified maximum count.
func prefix(Int) -> Publishers.Output<PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure>>
```

The `max` operator is returning the largest value at completion (and it's possible you're triggering completion more than once):

```
/// Publishes the maximum value received from the upstream publisher, after it finishes.
/// Available when Output conforms to Comparable.
func max() -> Publishers.Comparison<PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure>>
```

Comment: I know `prefix`, but the subscriber may need more values later. So I guess `PassthroughSubject` cannot guarantee that subscribers will receive the expected number of values?

Comment: It is correct that Subjects deliver any number of values until they are completed. I'm not sure exactly what behavior you are after, maybe `throttle` or `debounce` would work. You could also simply `map` the result and send [0...5] downstream discarding the others.